# Begin transaction está bloqueando todo meu banco de dados

Tags: php, sql-server, transações

Estou com um problema, tenho um *script* php que faz leitura de arquivos grandes em XML.

Antes de iniciar a inserção desses dados faço um *begin transaction* e no fim o *commit*, porém durante todo o processo que pode levar até 20 minutos meu banco de dados fica inutilizável, tanto pra quem está fazendo a importação (até aqui ok) tanto para outros computadores que não tem nada a ver com a tabela que está sendo populada, vocês podem me dar uma luz?

Comment: Qual banco de dados é? você da algum lock manualmente?

Comment: Estou utilizando o sql server 2008. Não utilizo nenhum lock, todas as configurações estão padrão de instalação no sql server

Comment: Posta o código para a nós darmos uma checada!

Comment: Poderia colocar parte do código php e da sql.

Comment: Hm, estou usando a classe Adodb para PHP com o driver mssqlnative. A chamada que ela executa é para a função "sqlsrv_begin_transaction" e depois disso faço os insert normalmente e então o commit. No meio dessa transaction estou executando alguns selects, vocês acham que as tabelas que executo o select dentro da trans estão sendo bloqueadas ?

Comment: Quando você chama *sqlsrv_begin_transaction* você nao passa nenhum parâmetro? E se pra cada select que voce fizer dentro dessa transação voce fizer dentro de uma nova transação? Já tentou isso?

Answer (score 1):

Bruno,

Quando abrimos uma transação todas as tabelas envolvidas do seu script ficarão bloqueadas para utilização até que a transação seja concluída. O SQL Server, e outros SGBDs, utilizam esta técnica para evitar que outros leiam um dado fantasma, sujo ou desatualizado que é um dado não confiável.

Encontrei uma explicação mais detalhada sobre este caso [Isolation Level](http://www.diegonogare.net/2013/01/transaction-isolation-level-voc-est-usando-certo/) . Neste link, você pode encontrar duas soluções para o caso:

1. Setar o Isolation Level para READ UNCOMMITTED nas queries fora da transação;
2. Utilizar a opção WITH (NOLOCK);

Segue um exemplo das suas utilizações:

Isolation Level:

```
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED         
    SELECT * FROM tbIsolationLevel
```

WITH (NOLOCK):

```
SELECT * FROM tbIsolationLevel WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Lembrando que você terá problemas de leitura de dados não confíaveis nas duas soluções.